# Export subscribers from Mailchimp via api

Tags: mailchimp

I am exporting the subscribers from my account on Mailchimp via export api. I can easily export the subscribers if a mention a list id.

I want to export all the subscribers without having to worry about the list ids. Instead of looping all the list ids, i just want to directly export all the subscribers irrespective of lists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible right now in the MailChimp API, you'll want to grab a list of your lists and then queue a batch operation for each one.

Note: Batch Operations are a part of API v3; the export API is slated to be removed.

Comment: Hi ToomuchPete, 

Could please explain how to create a batch operation to retrieve members from a list?

For Example,
I have used method and path request body parameters. 
EX : data = '{"operations" : [{"method" : "POST","path" : "lists/{list_id}/members"}]}';

But, the batch operation was returned successfully. But, the responese_body_url key value is empty.

Comment: That sounds like an issue for customer support, but I'll note that I _think_ the method should be GET if you're trying to retrieve.